# Unexpected side effect of font encoding

Tags: font-encodings

It is often recommended to include `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, but I have been hit by the following difference:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
texttt: \texttt{-->}

verb: \verb+-->+
\end{document}
```

Without `fontenc` both render the same `-->`. But with `fontenc` the first is rendered as `->`.

Are there other such differences to expect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my opinion, it was an oversight when the EC fonts were developed.

You can disable the ligatures (in `pdflatex`) with `microtype`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}

\DisableLigatures[-,?,!,<,>]{encoding=T1,family=tt*}

\begin{document}

texttt: \texttt{--> --->}

verb: \verb+--> --->+

\texttt{?` !` ff fi fl ffi ffl << >>}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without the `\DisableLigatures` line you'd get

[image]

With XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX there is no problem, because the monospaced font is loaded without TeX ligatures enabled.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

texttt: \texttt{--> --->}

verb: \verb+--> --->+

\texttt{?` !` ff fi fl ffi ffl << >>}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Does it make a difference where I add the line `\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}` so before or after? (I cannot see any, but then...)

Comment: @false `beramono` has no “hyphen ligatures”, as far as I can see. Depending on your needs, you may want to disable the “guillements ligatures”, though.